I'm getting access to the resource is forbidden error in Excel power query when I'm trying to import table from web
Getting access to resources is forbidden when I'm trying to get data from excel power query. Same is the issue with power bi.
This is the link
https://www.ameli.fr/medecin/exercice-liberal/facturation-remuneration/consultations-actes/maitrise-depassements
I tried clearing permission and tried the default web browser on powerbi none of the are working.
I want to get the data from table and image from this website
